# Image SlideShow using javaScript and HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing code for image slide Show using Java Script and HTML 5.  I am using SetInterval() method to call ImageSlider Function repeatedly. Problem is Imageslider function is called only once.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Online Booking</title>
</head>
<style>
iframe
{
display:block;
float:middle;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center
}
</style>
<body onload="init()">
<script>
function init()
{           
setInterval(imageSlider(),5000);
}
function staticVar()
{

if (staticVar.counter == undefined)
{
    staticVar.counter = 1
}
else
{
    staticVar.counter++
}
return staticVar.counter;
}
function imageSlider()
{
alert("sl");
var j= staticVar();     
var imgArray = new Array();
imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = '91.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'myBro.jpg';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'me.jpg';

document.getElementById("imageSlide").src = imgArray[j].src;
}
</script>
<iframe height="580" width="25%" src="91.jpg" id="imageSlide"> </iframe>
</body >
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
setInterval(imageSlider,5000);
```

instead of

```
setInterval(imageSlider(),5000);
```

Documentation on [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval).